# arcgis 10.1 account manager, authorizeSoftware script

Tags: arcgis-10.1, linux, arcgis-license-manager

I am trying to run "authorizeSoftware" file to complete creating new account manager in Arcgis 10.1, but after running

```
./authorizeSoftware
```

I got this message:

> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- Starting the ArcGIS Software Authorization Wizard
>
> Run this script with --help for additional information.
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- Unable to access X server (:0.0).  Please check your DISPLAY variable
>   or run this script in silent mode.  Run with the --help option for
>   more information

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to authorize ArcGIS Server on Linux? If so, why do you refer to ArcGIS License Manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're running the license manager on a Linux machine.

If you have a GUI installed, start it, then try to run the authorization.

If not, see this **[knowledge base article](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38412)** on how to set up a fake display environment and how to authorize from the command line.